# max count in having-clause

Tags: mysql, count, max, having-clause

I have to find the actors appeared first most times.

Recital(opera,actor,character,appearingOrder)

i've tried in this way:

```
select distinct R1.Actor, count(R1.Actor) as nro
from Recital R1
where R1.AppOrd='1'
group by Actor
having max(nro)
```

but it returns an empty table.
Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

This would show the top actor, however if there was a tie, it would only show one of the actors:

```
select R1.Actor, count(R1.Actor) as nro
from Recital R1
where R1.AppOrd='1'
group by R1.Actor
ORDER BY nro DESC
LIMIT 1;
```